# Save/read cookies in JS?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Is there any way to save/read cookies in the p5.js and p5.play libraries in JS? I'm making a proof of concept for a saving mechanism and I can't find how to save/read the cookies.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to save data locally and have no intent to communicate that information back to a server (e.g., for authentication or identification) you may want ot use `localStorage` instead of cookies.

p5.js has a simple [`storeItem`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/storeItem)/[`getItem`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/getItem) API that is basically a wrapper for `localSotrage` but it's a bit better: `localStorage` only works to store strings, but p5.js's API understands how to serialize and deserialize objects (and in particular p5.js data structures) as well.

Comment: Oh cool I've never seen the `storeItem()` and `getItem()` functions before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

p5.js is "just" JavaScript, so anything you can do in JavaScript, you can do in p5.js. That means if you can't find what you're looking for in the p5.js [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/), you can often Google for a more general JavaScript solution.

In your case, try googling "JavaScript save and read cookies" for a ton of results.

I would start here:

- [JavaScript Cookies - W3SChools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- [Document.cookie - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
- [How do I create and read a value from cookie? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825683/873165)